# Websphere 8.0/MyFaces2.0 and PrimeFaces 6 not compatible?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere

I'm currently trying to use **PrimeFaces** (not mobile) for my **WebSphere 8.0** application. The basic stuff like **p:dataTable** seems to **work**. But if I want to use the fancy stuff of PrimeFaces, like filter columns or pagination, there is either a NullPointerException or the additional function is not rendered at all.
The Nullpointer occurred when entering something in the generated filtering field in the table. The setter method that is called is given *null* as parameter.
The pagination on the other hand is not even being rendered. (I used the templates of the PrimeFace showcase)
Weird thing is, the sorting by column function is working fine.
I haven't done any big adjustments, just put the .jar file to my classpath and disabled all themes of PrimeFaces in my web.xml. That's it.

When I inspect the network and stuff in chrome there is no exception thrown in the console when loading the page.

Now I'm thinking that this version of PrimeFaces is not compatible with MyFaces2.0 that is used by WAS8.0.

Is that the case? If so, what version of PF would be compatible? Or would it be possible to load a newer Version of MyFaces and dependencies and put it in WAS to use this version instead of the current used version?

Or maybe I have to make some adjustments to my application?

If everything is not possible, do you know an alternative to PF to easily create tables?

Answer (score 0):

Using a third-party JSF provider with WebSphere is documented here (the doc is for 8.5.5, but it's the same procedure in 8.0): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html

Basically, the answer is to put your provider (along with the corresponding API) into a shared library, set that library to use an isolated class loader, and associate that shared library with your web app.  That will tell the web module's class loader to search your shared library before it delegates to server class loaders, and it'll find your JSF provider first when your app attempts to use JSF.